# Python - array of non-unique values based on corresponding maximum in another array

Tags: python

I have an array of non-unique numbers (x) and another array of the same length with some values (y). I would like to return an array (z) which is the same length as x but only shows the unique values of x when y is a maximum.
E.g.

```
x = [0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3]
y = [1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1]
z = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```

Does anyone please know how I can get the array z?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
x = [0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3]
y = [1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1]

my = max(y)

z = [xi if my == yi else 0 for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]
print(z)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```

The above list comprehension is *equivalent* to the following `for` loop:

```
z = []
for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
    if yi == my:
        z.append(xi)
    else:
        z.append(0)
```